# Use vtk.js / glsl files in angular cli app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, vtk.js

I try to use vtk.js in my angular cli application and added the vtk.js to my angular-cli.json.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/OpenGL/glsl/vtkVolumeVS.glsl
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:10)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type....
```

How can I use a glsl loader with angular cli?

Of course without ejection of angular cli.

Comment: You should probably eject webpack config from Angular CLI and follow vtk.js webpack configuration documentation https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/docs/intro_vtk_as_es6_dependency.html

Comment: Had the same issue with an other lib and seems there is no way around ejection of the Webpack configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://codeburst.io/customizing-angular-cli-6-build-an-alternative-to-ng-eject-a48304cd3b21). You don't have to eject since Angular 6 has disabled ejection. Just follow the article and the `extra-webpack.config.js` content is as follows:

```
  module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.glsl$/i,
        include: /node_modules(\/|\\)vtk\.js(\/|\\)/,
        loader: 'shader-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: /node_modules(\/|\\)vtk\.js(\/|\\)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=env',
      },
      {
        test: /\.worker\.js$/,
        include: /node_modules(\/|\\)vtk\.js(\/|\\)/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'worker-loader',
            options: { inline: true, fallback: false },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

of course, you have to install the dependency `vtk.js` and `kw-web-suit`. Then it should be compiled successfully.
if you meet the error which says "global is not defined" in browser's developer mode, then add `(window as any).global = window;` to Angular's `polyfills.ts`.
It works for me on Angular 6 with the latest vtk.js.

Comment: hey, I am also trying to use vtk.js in my angular project and tried you suggestion by replacing builder with custom-webpack builder in `angular.json`. I get `An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.` error. Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: I downgraded custom-webpack to `8.4.1` but I get the following error `ERROR in ./node_modules/vtk.js/Sources/Rendering/Core/Actor/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):` I don't understand what this error means ?

Comment: I have been not doing these for a long time, I'm afriad that I can't help. What about using three.js? We switch to using three.js, because vtk.js is some what hard to use.

Comment: thanks for update, my needs are more on manufacturing simulation where as `three.js` seems to generic 3D library

Comment: Hey I found this link useful and it solved my problem https://github.com/Kitware/vtk-js/issues/1003#issuecomment-676477880, maybe you can add it to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to use the pre-build umd version of vtk.js?

Comment: Can you also provide more details on how to use pre-build version of this library?

Comment: The [issue](https://github.com/Kitware/vtk-js/issues/608) provide a codepen example loading vtk.js from a CDN and performing basic rendering actions.